# How to make a SSIS package to monitor the status of a column in a DB table and then execute the ssis package if the status=1?

Tags: ssis

How to make a SSIS package to monitor the status of a column in a DB table and then execute the ssis package if the status=1

Comment: Are you sure you need a whole SSIS package and not just a trigger? Here's a [short explanation](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/triggers-sql-server-t15510/) and [another one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server).

Answer (score 2):

You could set up the SSIS package in a SQL Agent job without a defined schedule.  Then create a trigger on the status field of the table.  When the status changes from 0 to 1, execute the job that will then run the SSIS package.

Your trigger could look something like the following.  I have not checked the syntax and I recommend tweaking it in testing to verify that it launches appropriately.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON TableName 
AFTER UPDATE
IF UPDATE (status) AND status = 1
BEGIN
  EXEC msdb..sp_start_job 
     @job_name = 'JobName';
GO
END
```

The following link illustrates different approaches to executing a SQL Agent job.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1730/different-ways-to-execute-a-sql-agent-job/

Hope this helps.
Kosh